# Having issue with lists

Tags: html, css, smarty

im using smarty engine i need little help my lists are showing gaps when some season has more episodes than the last one so it shows gap i want it to auto adjust gap when some season has more episodes than last one. here is my smarty code.

```
<div class="seasons">
{foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
    {if !isset($lastSeason)}
        <div class="tv_container">

            <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
    {elseif $lastSeason != $val.season}
        </div>
        <div class="tv_container" style="float: left;">

            <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
    {/if}
<ul class="listings episodeListings">
 <li class="">
 {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$val.episodetitle}">{if $val.episodetitle}
                    <span class="epnum">({$val.episode.embeds|@count} links)</span>
                    <span class="">{$val.episodetitle|truncate:50:"...":true}</span>{/if}</a>
                {else}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}<div class="left">
{foreach from=$val.languages item=flag key=k}
<img src="{$embed_languages[$flag].flag}" style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
{/foreach}
</div>   </a>
                {/if}
                </li>    
            </ul>
        {assign var=lastSeason value=$val.season}
{/foreach}
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here an [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/f8r6fxxy/) example i want season season 14 to auto adjust under season 17 its just an example some times seasons have 12 episdes and other 20 so it make a huge gap i just want to auto adjust every season under the next season no matter how many episodes it have.

Comment: I'm afraid what I assume you want isn't possible in CSS. Apart from that, why are you using one `<ul>` per episode?

Comment: as you see its loop which also adds season name in h2 so if i use ul before that i cant get season name, i know it isnt possible in CSS  thats why i gave smarty code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the type of layout that you want to achieve?

[image]

Comment: yes same like that but only two blocks left and right

Comment: Afaik this is not possible with any standard layout method. Properly using float will make the next row always begin on a new line, while using flex boxes will make all lists in one row equal height. And columns also screw it up, since colums wreck the ordering you want, showing item 1 above item 2 rather than left of it. I've been wondering how to acheive this myself for a long time, and will soon fomulate it as a question here.

Comment: lol....this can be achieved by using odd even method but it isnt working on my side because im using smarty and it auto generating list. I just want the columns to auto adjust height after irregular value of content.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: another dirty way that could work (but it is not pretty) is to have 2 divs floated, but output all content into one column (with the same width as it will be in two columns after) and then use javascript to check the height of each season and place it in the correct of column: keep track of the height of the height so far and place it in the "shorter" one.
That way the "flow" of the document would still be kinda in order.

EDIT: i just saw that that is not what the goal was. sorry for the wrong solution and someone from the more experienced people can tell me if i should keep it here anyway or remove it...

My guess/understanding of a problem is that you want to have the seasons aligned vertically - so that all the seasons start in the same height and when for example one season has 10 parts on the left side and another season next to it has 20, there will be a blank space under the left "column" (season with only 10 episodes) and then the 2 next seasons will start verticaly aligned.
see the [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yb66p44p/) for a better idea what the result looks like

If that is the result you are looking for, all you have to do is clear the floats, a simple way of doing that is adding a div between the columns that should be grouped together

```
<div class="clear-floats"></div>
```

and then in css add this

```
.clear-floats { clear:both; }
```

considering you have a fix width of one column i'm guessing that you don't always want to have 2 columns only but it should be "as many as fit" to the screen width?
If that is the case my first guess would be to make some javascript to get screen width and divide it by width of one column and then insert this "clear divs" after every n-th column.
But i'm sure there is a better way that some will (hopefully) point out

hope that helps at least a bit

Comment: Nope, that's easy to achieve, but afaik I understood the OP, he's asking this vertical whitespace to be always of identical height (like for example 20px), not dependent on content of the container above it. See my layout assumption below.

Comment: i see that now yeah :)
what could work is making 2 div's that are floated and put the seasons inside them, but that would require the change in html generation, don't know if that is an option?